# How to get all authors for current state of git?

Tags: git

I've been trying to find all the authors of a git project, so that I can ask about relicensing their commits. I figured there'd be no point in contacting all the authors, as there may have been some who have had code in the codebase, but it was removed. So I wanted to contact only the authors with commits which are visible in the current HEAD.

I was told that git log had this capability, but I couldn't find anything on it except for something like:

```
git log --format='%an <%ae>'
```

Which does sort of what I'd like to achieve except it doesn't exclude authors without code in the current codebase.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you'll need something involving `git blame`, but I don't know the details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IANAL, but as for the relicensing I am not so sure that it is enough to have only the permission of the authors who have any code in the current project. After all their contributions / commits somehow lead to the current state of the project.

That aside you may want to take a look at [git blame](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-blame). It shows what line of a file was introduced in which commit by which author. This should get you closer to the solution of your problem. Maybe some additional post processing with `awk ... | sort | uniq` can do the rest.

However, `git blame` only shows information for a single file, so you would have to repeat that for all files in the repository.

In the root directory of the Git repository, you could use a shell command like this on Linux systems:

```
find ./ -name '*.cpp' -print0 | xargs -0 -i git blame --show-email {} | awk ' { print $3 } ' | sort | uniq
```

This searches for C++ source files (extension *.cpp) with find and performs a `git blame` on all of those files. The option `--show-email` of  `git blame` shows e-mail addresses instead of names, which are easier to filter for, because names can consist of several words, while an address is usually just one. `awk` then gets only the third column of the output, which is the mail address. (First is the short commit hash, second one is the file name.) Finally, `sort | uniq` is used to get rid of duplicates, showing each address only once.

(Untested, but it may point you in the right direction.)

If you just want every author who ever comitted anything to the repository, just use

```
git log --format='%an <%ae>' | sort | uniq
```

instead.

Comment: I managed to adapt the command to get more or less my desired output, thanks for the detailed answer. I will definitely be speaking to a lawyer, it was mainly just an idea I had.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git blame](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) to determine the list of current contributors:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

IFS='
'
for f in `git ls-tree -r --name-only ${1:-HEAD}`; do
        git blame -w -C -p "$f" | sed -n \
                -e '/^author /{ s/^author //; h; }' \
                -e '/^author-mail /{ s/^author-mail //; H; x; s/\n/ /p; }'
done | sort -u
```

You should pass `-w` to ignore whitespace changes and -C to follow moves and copies to achieve more accurate attribution.  Also, running it with `-p` outputs in porcelain mode for robust parsing of the output (i.e., will not get tripped up by spaces in file names.)

Note that while `-w` and `-C` should give you better results than without them, this is still just an heuristic and may not be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: @JoshdeKock, good catch.  I think it was an easy fix, though; I was missing a semi-colon before the closing curly-brace.  If nothing else, it at least works on FreeBSD now, too.

Answer (score 1):

The [git-fame](https://github.com/casperdcl/git-fame#readme) program lists contributors according to the number of *surviving* locs, so matches what's requested.

Install it with `pip install git-fame`

```
~$ git fame --cost hour,month
Blame: 100%|██████████| 74/74 [00:00<00:00, 96.51file/s]
Total commits: 1173
Total ctimes: 1055
Total files: 180
Total hours: 255.1
Total loc: 2716
Total months: 8.7
| Author                     |   hrs |   mths |   loc |   coms |   fils |  distribution   |
|:---------------------------|------:|-------:|------:|-------:|-------:|:----------------|
| Casper da Costa-Luis       |   100 |      7 |  2171 |    770 |     63 | 79.9/65.6/35.0  |
| Stephen Larroque           |    16 |      1 |   243 |    202 |     19 | 8.9/17.2/10.6   |
| Kyle Altendorf             |     6 |      0 |    41 |     31 |      3 | 1.5/ 2.6/ 1.7   |
| Guangshuo Chen             |     2 |      0 |    35 |     18 |      6 | 1.3/ 1.5/ 3.3   |
| Matthew Stevens            |     2 |      0 |    32 |      3 |      2 | 1.2/ 0.3/ 1.1   |
| Noam Yorav-Raphael         |     3 |      0 |    23 |     11 |      4 | 0.8/ 0.9/ 2.2   |
| Daniel Panteleit           |     2 |      0 |    16 |      2 |      2 | 0.6/ 0.2/ 1.1   |
| Mikhail Korobov            |     2 |      0 |    15 |     11 |      6 | 0.6/ 0.9/ 3.3   |
| Hadrien Mary               |     3 |      0 |    15 |     31 |     10 | 0.6/ 2.6/ 5.6   |
| Johannes Hansen            |     2 |      0 |    14 |      1 |      2 | 0.5/ 0.1/ 1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use shortlog (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog):

```
$ git shortlog -se
    26  Bart Simpson <elbarto@springfield.com>
     6  Homer Simpson <homer.j.simpson@springfield.com>
   103  Lisa Simpson <jazz@springfield.com>
    34  Marge Simpson <marge@springfield.com>
```

This will print out a list of all authors in your history sorted alphabetically, including email addresses and the number of commits per author.

By default this analyzes the history leading to `HEAD`, i.e. everything leading to the current commit.
I think this is exactly what you want.

You can sort by commit count using `-n` to find out the most important committers.

```
$ git shortlog -sen
   103  Lisa Simpson <jazz@springfield.com>
    34  Marge Simpson <marge@springfield.com>
    26  Bart Simpson <elbarto@springfield.com>
     6  Homer Simpson <homer.j.simpson@springfield.com>
```

Comment: Please read the question, I wanted to get all the authors for the visible commits (from HEAD) only.

Comment: I think I now understand what you want, but your question is still misleading. I understood that you want to find out all authors which have contributed to the current `HEAD` due to licensing (excluding those who worked on branches which are not reachable by the current `HEAD`). This is what `shortlog` does. Contacting only authors which appear in the latest `git blame` does not ensure that they are the owner of the code. If I reformat an entire file then I am the latest author in `git blame`. That doesn't make me the author of the code.